# KnockOutJS: Very odd behaviour with descendantsComplete and components(custom elements)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, components, custom-element, knockout-3.0

Knockout version: 3.5.1

I have a custom element on my main .html file like so:

`<my-component></my-component>`

Inside I have a form to which I am attaching jQuery validation which is not working because when the line `$("#myForm").validate` is called, the form is not yet in the DOM.

I created a very basic jsFiddle to illustrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/sb1of04g/

Notice how if you remove the timeout, the result is 0. I get the same result if I move the alert below `ko.applyBindings(new Test());`

I want my jQuery validation code to run after the component is 100% loaded.

In my project I'm using custom elements and requirejs/text so to fix the issue I tried the below approach:

`<my-component data-bind="event: { descendantsComplete: $root.OnComponentReady() }"></my-component>`

```
self.OnComponentReady = function()
{
    $("#myForm").validate ...
}
```

But no luck, OnComponentReady is executed correctly but the form is still not in the DOM.

This is when things got funny. Inside my-component I have another component, footer-component which is at the very bottom of the parent component and if I change my code to the below, I get the correct behaviour.

`<my-component></my-component>`

`<footer-component data-bind="event: { descendantsComplete: $root.OnComponentReady() }"></footer-component>`

Like this, when OnComponentReady is executed the form is available and I can attach jQuery validation to it. It also works if I move footer-component at the top of my-component.

I was under the impression that descendantsComplete fires after the component finished loading, similarly to jQuery's `$(document).ready`. Is this not the case? I'm not entirely sure I will have a child component in the future so ideally descendantsComplete is attached to the parent component.

**Edit:** I just realised that if I move the .validate code from my main ViewModel($root) to the Component ViewModel, I get the correct behaviour without the descendantsComplete event.

Comment: I presume it does what you want when you tested it in FireFox?

Comment: Unfortunately no, incidentally I use Firefox and I get the same behaviour, descendantsComplete works as expected only when attached to the child component.

Comment: Then it is (most likely) **not** related to the FireFox different implementation of CE DOM ready behaviour.